# Highlight Month Columns based on dates in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I would highlight, in Google Sheet, the columns of months based on dates in col AA:
dd/mm/yyyy (start date) - dd/mm/yyyy (end date).

Example:
Col AA ---> 25/05/2022 - 06/09/2022
The columns that must be highlighted: from May to September.

Comment: see `mike steelson` tab in your spreadsheet

Comment: I cannot change the name of the headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a much simpler formula:

```
=(EOMONTH(DATEVALUE("1/"&C$1);0)>$A2)*(DATEVALUE("1/"&C$1)<=$B2)
```

this works for current year.

If you want to use another year add it to string in `DATEVALUE` function, i.e. `=DATEVALUE("1/"&C$1&"/2020")`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to change headers of column and put inside the first day of each month. Then apply a format as MMMM.

Conditionnal formatting formula:

```
=and(C$1>=EOMONTH($A2;-1)+1;C$1<=EOMONTH($B2;0))
```

if you can't change headers, the formula will be:

```
=and(MATCH(proper(text(index(split($AA2;" - ");1);"MMMM"));{"Gennaio";"Febbraio";"Marzo";"Aprile";"Maggio";"Giugno";"Luglio";"Agosto";"Settembre";"Ottobre";"Novembre";"Dicembre"};0)<=MATCH(B$1;{"Gennaio";"Febbraio";"Marzo";"Aprile";"Maggio";"Giugno";"Luglio";"Agosto";"Settembre";"Ottobre";"Novembre";"Dicembre"};0);MATCH(proper(text(iferror(index(split($AA2;" - ");2);"31/12/2022"*1);"MMMM"));{"Gennaio";"Febbraio";"Marzo";"Aprile";"Maggio";"Giugno";"Luglio";"Agosto";"Settembre";"Ottobre";"Novembre";"Dicembre"};0)>=MATCH(B$1;{"Gennaio";"Febbraio";"Marzo";"Aprile";"Maggio";"Giugno";"Luglio";"Agosto";"Settembre";"Ottobre";"Novembre";"Dicembre"};0))
```

Comment: I cannot change the name of the headers

Comment: if you apply format MMMM the name will appear to be the same! If you can't do that, it will be too complex but not impossible!

Comment: Yes, I cannot change the format. The name must be the same.

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: Perfect, but I cannot have the col A and B in the same tab. Could you move in another tab?

Comment: ok, updated ...

Comment: Very thanks! Regards.